# Checkbox normal a iCheck(plugin) con evento click

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

Mi problema es este, tengo tres casillas al seleccionar una actualiza la BD con el valor de la casilla, todo esto me funciona bien, este es mi codigo:

index.php

```
<input type = "radio" id = "chk" data-id = "1"  name="1" value="5" /> SI
<input type = "radio" id = "chk2" data-id = "1" name="1" value="1" /> NO
<input type = "radio" id = "chk3" data-id = "1" name="1" value="0" /> N/A
```

Micheck.js

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("chk"),
    ajax = function(url){
        var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? 
                  new XMLHttpRequest() : 
                  new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") || 
                  new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    };

     checkbox.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var estado = this.value, //this es el elemento en este caso el checkbox y el value obtiene el valor de value
        id = this.getAttribute("data-id"), //El valor del 'data-id'
        url = "cl3.php?estado=" + estado + "&id=" + id;
        console.log(estado);

    ajax(url); //Ejecutó la petición asíncrona, enviando los valores
    }, false);
```

Y mi php checktabla.php

```
<?php
include "../config/config.php";

if(!empty($_GET) ){
//Recibo los datos 
$id = $_GET['id'];
$estado = $_GET['estado'];

//Actualizo los datos
$sql = "update preguntas set valor=\"$estado\" where id=$id";

$update=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
//mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE preguntas SET valor=$estado WHERE id=$id");
}else{
    echo "sin datos";
}
?>
```

Todo funciona correctamente, mi verdadero problema es que estoy usando iCheck que es un plugin para personalizar las casillas, y trato de hacer lo mismo pero ahora con el iCheck pero no me sale, las modificaciones las hago en el JS pero me funciona y no se como pasarlo del check normal al plugin de iCheck

Comment: Y el plugin no tendrá un LocalStorage ó Cookie...? ... A lo mejor limpiando la caché de los navegadores...

Comment: Mira ya revise la documentación [http://icheck.fronteed.com/#callbacks], en la parte de los Callbacks existe algo que se llama ifClicked, lo que entiendo es que hace un evento como onclick, pero no se como implementarlo con mi código de arriba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya solucione mi pregunta, aquí está la respuesta, por si a alguien le puede ayudar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#SI').on('ifClicked', function(event) {
        ajax = function(url){
        var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? 
                  new XMLHttpRequest() : 
                  new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") || 
                  new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    };

    var estado = this.value;
    id = this.getAttribute("data-id");
    url = "action/checktabla.php?estado=" + estado + "&id=" + id;

    console.log(estado,id);
     ajax(url); //Ejecutó la petición asíncrona, enviando los valores
     false;
  })
});
```

Si funciona y hace la actualización en BD.